# Reason behind inner shell excitation phenomenon

Tags: photons, atomic-physics

Is there any simple explanation of inner-shell phenomenon. I wanted to know that why photons with high energy do not excite outer shell electrons.

Comment: Does "excited" include ionization?   If so, then high energy photons do excite outer shell electrons.

Comment: @garyp In the X-ray spectra a fast particle can penetrate to the inner most shell and knockout an electron. My question is that why it doesn’t knockout the electron in the outer shell. Also, how can we find the probability of ionizing each shell?

Comment: @user201949 - who says the x-ray can't knock out an outer shell electron? That does not mean that a given photon can't do one or the other. Calculating the transition probabilities for interactions with each shell is certainly done, but is a complex answer.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for your answer. But, is there any explanation that why x-ray does not knock down only the outer shell electron. Also, can you provide me a resource about finding the probability of interactions with each shell?

Comment: There are entire books written about VUV and x-ray photoionization. Check with your local friendly librarian as to which are available to you. There is one by Becker and Shirley that I've looked through...

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Your answers are really useful for me.